# ARC and Instance Variable without @property and @synthesize

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I'm wondering how ARC knows how to work when I create variables without @property like in this case:

```
@interface MyClass: NSObject
{
    NSString *name;
}
-(NSString*)name;
-(void)setName:(NSString*)the_name;
```

have I to use __strong keyword like in this code? :

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
    NSString __strong *name;
}
```

Or I have to write accessor methods in this way ?:

```
-(void)setName:(NSString*)the_name{
   name = __strong the_name;
}
```

Comment: __strong is the default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you do not need to do anything special: `__strong` keyword is *implied* when there is no ARC keyword.

**EDIT** You do not need to use `__strong` in the setter either: ARC knows to retain `the_name`, because `name` is already a `__strong` reference.

Comment: So I can avoid the __strong keyword and ARC works as expected for the **name** variable ?

Comment: I edit my question... because the doubt is probably related with the implementation of the accessor methods